# What color is used for a read-only CEdit in MFC/Win32?

Tags: mfc, winapi

I am trying to find if there is a system color used here, so I can use the same value in my custom control. But I cannot find any reference, and none of these [system colors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724371(VS.85).aspx) sound right.

Is there a sys-color or constant I can use? Failing that, what's the RGB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Dialog's default background color.

Try this `::GetSysColor(COLOR_3DFACE)`